# Uncomment an XML element through regex in Java

Tags: java, regex, xml, comments

My XML looks like below,

```
<!-- Service Defs -->

<!-- <serviceName = "${NASA_Freedom.level.mission}"
                 MaxTimeOut = "20" minSpareHyperThread = "10" />
-->
```

And I just need to uncomment the serviceName element:

```
<serviceName = "${NASA_Freedom.level.mission}"
                 MaxTimeOut = "20" minSpareHyperThread = "10" />
```

The following code doesn't seem to do the trick:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(<!--).*<serviceName = \\"${NASA_Freedom.*(-->)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.replaceAll(""));
}
```

This also seems like a bad way to handle this. Unfortunately I cannot do anything about the XML file so this seems to be the only way. How do I un comment like above?

Comment: Your code shouldn't compile, since you aren't escaping properly.

Comment: Your XML is not well formed, there is no attribute name

Comment: @NicolasFilotto - unfortunately, it parses ok.

Comment: @sin it parses OK because it is a comment, once it will be uncommented it won't be well formed anymore

Comment: @NicolasFilotto - I think the <element> will be malformed, but it probably will parse ok as long as it can be matched by `<[\w:]+\s+(?:(?:(?:"[\S\s]*?")|(?:'[\S\s]*?'))|(?:[^>]*?))+\s*/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way

Find: `"<!--(?:(?!-->)[\\S\\s])*?(<serviceName\\s+(?:(?:(?:\"[\\S\\s]*?\")|(?:'[\\S\\s]*?'))|(?:[^>]*?))+\\s*/>)[\\S\\s]*?-->"`

Replace: `"$1"` (*basically replacing group 0 with group 1 in the string*)

Expanded:

```
 <!-- 
 (?:
      (?! --> )
      [\S\s] 
 )*?

 (                             # (1 start)
      <serviceName \s+ 
      (?:
           (?:
                (?: " [\S\s]*? " )
             |  (?: ' [\S\s]*? ' )
           )
        |  (?: [^>]*? )
      )+
      \s* />
 )                             # (1 end)

 [\S\s]*? -->
```

Input:

```
<!-- Service Defs -->

<!-- <serviceName = "${NASA_Freedom.level.mission}"
                 MaxTimeOut = "20" minSpareHyperThread = "10" />
-->
```

Output:

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 25 , len 122 ) 
<!-- <serviceName = "${NASA_Freedom.level.mission}"
                 MaxTimeOut = "20" minSpareHyperThread = "10" />
-->  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 30 , len 112 ) 
<serviceName = "${NASA_Freedom.level.mission}"
                 MaxTimeOut = "20" minSpareHyperThread = "10" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this regular expression:

```
<!--\s*(<serviceName\s*=\s*\"\${NASA_Freedom.level.mission}\".*?)\s*-->
```

It's important to properly escape characters such a quotes so that your Java syntax is valid.

You'll want to use `Pattern.DOTALL` as an argument to `Pattern.compile` so that the pattern will match across multiple lines (basically tells the regex engine to match `.` against newline characters).

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<!--\s*(<serviceName\s*=\s*\"\${NASA_Freedom.level.mission}\".*?)\s*-->", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

If you replace each match with the contents of capture group 1 it should remove the commenting.

EDIT:

If you instead prefer to match the comments and remove them by replacing them with empty strings, use this regular expression instead:

```
(<!--\s*)<serviceName\s*=\s*\"\${NASA_Freedom.level.mission}\".*?(\s*-->)
```

Basically just inverses the grouping from the first regular expression.

Comment: The match is rather the content and not the comment right? If I surround the comment (<!--) then its not getting replaced.

Comment: This is matching the content, so for each match you need to replace the matched text with the contents of group 1. Kind of the inverse of matching the comments and replacing them with empty strings.

Comment: @TimFalony Added an edit so you can keep your logic in replacing the comments

Answer (score 1):

To uncomment a given patter you can proceed as next:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
    "(?s)<!--(.*" + 
     Pattern.quote("<serviceName = \"${NASA_Freedom.level.mission}\"") + 
    "((?!-->).)*)-->"
);
System.out.println(p.matcher(xml).replaceAll("$1"));
```

You will need:

1. To set the flag `s` to enable [`dotall mode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) as it is a multiline content so we want that dot also covers line terminator,
2. then you will need to use [`Pattern.quote(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote-java.lang.String-) to quote your pattern and
3. finally replace the whole expression with the first capturing group corresponding here to what we have between `<!--` and `-->`.

**NB:** Once uncommented this expression will brake your XML as it won't be well formed anymore.

**NB2:** I added a zero-width negative lookahead to prevent having `-->` in the captured group which allow to avoid affecting others comments

Comment: Its removing the first starting comment (before Service Defs) and the last closing comment.

Comment: fixed, with a zero-width negative lookahead to prevent having --> in the captured group, please check again